# onResume called on "dead" fragments - how to recover correctly?

Tags: java, android, android-support-library

I develop an App with Fragments from the support library. I only use one Activity.
The layout consists of a Coordinator Layout with a Collapsing Toolbar Layout and a Navigation View.
When selecting a Navigation Item I execute the following in the NavigationItemSelectedListener:

```
switch (item.getItemId()) {
                default:
                    return false;
                case R.id.mainmenu_start:
                    navi.clear();
                    navi.navigate(new StartFragment(), R.id.fragment_container);
                    return true;
                // ... More menu entries
            }
```

So when selecting a new Item I clear the backstack (`navi.clear()`) and replace the displayed fragment with a new one.

The problem I have is: The "old" (replaced) fragments **don't get deleted / detached**.

So when I navigate to the StartFragment, then navigate to another fragment and then again choose the StartFragment, the `onResume` gets called twice:
Once on the "old" / first StartFragment, once on the newly created one.

How can I avoid this behavior? I either want to reuse existing fragments (the first one) **or** create a new one - but using both leads to massive problems...

To investigate this behavior I gave each fragment a unique (incremental) ID: When navigating to the new Fragment, onResume is called on several older Fragments, but not on all of them.
For example: I always choose the same menu entry for navigation. This are the "events" occuring, where the number indicates the Fragment ID (all fragments are the same class (StartFragment)):

1. Create 1, Resume 1
2. Create 2, Resume 1, Resume 2
3. Create 3, Resume 1, Resume 3
4. Create 4, Resume 2, Resume 3, Resume 4

So sometimes the "old" fragments are missing and come back later. onResume is also called on completely different fragments sometimes. (So when I opened Fragment 2 earlier, onResume on Fragment 2 is also called when creating a new Fragment 1...)

**For completeness**
The navigation functions:

```
public void clear() {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((MainActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
}



public void navigate(Fragment fragment, int container, HashMap<String, Pair<String, View>> sharedElements) {
    this.hideKeyboard();
    FragmentTransaction ft = ((MainActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(container, fragment);
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();
    ((MainActivity)context).getDrawerLayout().closeDrawers();
}
```

Comment: First thought: Have you tried popBackStackImmediate instead of popBackStack ? Any difference?

Comment: Thank you :) This seems to be the correct solution! Maybe you want to post this as an Answer, so I can accept it

Comment: Sure, I will repost it as a separate answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting as an answer for future reference.

I think your problem is that [popBackStack()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#popBackStack) does not have immediate effect but is scheduled to run on next event loop pass, which in your case is too late and yields undesired effects. What should help is forcing fragment manager transaction to finish immidietly.

It could be achieved either by calling [executePendingTransactions()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#executePendingTransactions()) or in this particular case by [popBackStackImmediate()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html)